# Can you tell me if my code is right or wrong?

Tags: reactjs, api, react-hooks, fetch-api

Page1 code

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import Header from '../Components/Header'
import MainQuiz from '../Components/MainQuiz'

const Turner = () => {

  const [select, setSelect] = useState();
  
  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      <div className='text-center fs-3 text-uppercase'>Turner</div>
      <div className="container p-5">
        <select className="form-select" aria-label="Default select example" value={select} onChange={e => setSelect(e.target.value)}>
          <option selected>Select The Quiz</option>
          <option value="1">Turner 1</option>
          <option value="2">Turner 2</option>
          <option value="3">Turner 3</option>
          <option value="4">Turner 4</option>
          
        </select> 

        <MainQuiz value={select}/>
      </div> 
    </>
  )
}

export default Turner
```

Page2 code

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

const MainQuiz = (props) => {
    const [data, setData] = useState([])
    
    const url = `https://quizstcapi.herokuapp.com/turner/${props.value}`

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchData()
    }, [])

    const fetchData = () => {
        fetch(url)
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((responce) => {
            setData(responce);
        })
    }
  return (
    <div>
        <h4> {props.value} </h4>
        <h4> {url} </h4>
        {data.map((item,i)  => (
            <>
            <h3> {i} </h3>
            <h3> {item.Question} </h3>
            <h5> {item.Option1} </h5>
            <h5> {item.Option2} </h5>
            <h5> {item.Option3} </h5>
            <h5> {item.Option4} </h5>
            </>
        ))}
    </div>
  )
}

export default MainQuiz
```

I press ctrl+s in page 2 for fetch.

My problem is I cant fetch api directly. for fetch i need to choose option than come back to my code and press ctrl+s then it fetch the api i choose but i need is when i choose it directy show data of apis

here is the some images
after choosing

https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/trulyrockmusics.appspot.com/o/3.png?alt=media&token=a91f05f5-eff8-4f3b-aa53-324ed58f1c8e

after pressing ctrl+s

https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/trulyrockmusics.appspot.com/o/4.png?alt=media&token=7b7a9935-fa0c-4835-9c0f-705bc13ee124

Kindly give me a solution for this. thanks

Comment: Do not post your code as images.

Comment: Now i upadated my question

Comment: I am using VS code and ctrl+s means save

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although your question is a bit hard to make sense of, my crystal ball is telling the issue is your data loading isn't aware of the `value` prop changing, since you compute `url` outside of the effect that actually loads the data.

Then, you'll need to make `value` a dependency of the effect, so when the `value` changes (when you change it in the select and pass it down to `MainQuiz`, the effect is re-run.

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react'

function MainQuiz({value}) {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    setData(null);
    fetch(`https://quizstcapi.herokuapp.com/turner/${value}`)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then(setData);
  }, [value]);

  if (!data) return <>Loading...</>;

  return (
    <div>
      {data.map(...)}
    </div>
  );
}
```